# Where is the Moon Whistle Cave Raider for Search Quest?

Tags: made-in-abyss-binary-star

The side quest "Search Quest" asks you to find a Moon Whistle Cave Raider in the third layer of the Abyss. I've found the quest icon in the Rock Slide Hall by the entrance to the Freezing Hot Mines, but I don't see the cave raider. I suspect the actual location may be in a different cave higher up.

Where can I find the missing Moon Whistle Cave Raider for Search Quest?

[image: Map with Search Quest marker]
[image: The marked location with no cave raider in sight]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Moon Whistle Cave Raider is located at Rock Slide Hall in a cave around 5957m. The cave has two entrances: one near the center of the wall at 5968m with a ledge sticking out of the cave, and one on the right side at 5980m that you'll need to climb into from the side.

[image: Entrance at 5968m]

Find either one of these entrances then head into the cave to find the Moon Whistle.

[image: The missing Moon whistle]